# Hide child products in parent product page under grouped product in WooCommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, product

Most past answers are about hiding child items from listing and search results. I'm trying to hide the child items from the parent product page.

The reason is I'm doing a modification to allow something like "Buy 1 Free 1" in grouped products, meaning if you buy parent item, you get child item too! No need to click on child item and add it to the cart. It's "forced" into your cart.

I know I can use WooCommerce Chained Products but another plugin I'm using is not compatible with it.

[I wish to hide these child products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzJRv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your active theme functions.php

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'wc_product_display_css_overrides');

function wc_product_display_css_overrides() {
    echo "<style>.woocommerce-grouped-product-list{ display:none;}</style>";
}
```

Comment: Right. I did the same thing, but under Additional CSS in Customizer.